# Query inside query returned "as a column"

Tags: sql, select, count, mariadb

I like to list all companies in a table along with the number of admins that each specific company has.

The tables:

```
companies
id
name
...

users
id
company_id
...

groups ('id' = 1 has 'name' = admin)
id
name 

users_groups
id
user_id
group_id
```

To list all 'companies' I write this:

```
SELECT companies.name
FROM companies
```

To get the number of 'admin' in one specific 'company'(with a given id) I write this

```
SELECT COUNT (users.id) 
FROM users, companies, users_groups WHERE
users.company_id = companies.id AND 
users_groups.user_id = users.id AND
users_groups.group_id = 1
```

So how can I merge these two questions? This fails:

```
SELECT 
  companies.name, 
    (
      SELECT COUNT (users.id) 
      FROM users, companies, users_groups WHERE
      users.company_id = companies.id AND 
      users_groups.user_id = users.id AND
      users_groups.group_id = 1
    ) 
  as admins_in_company
FROM users, companies, users_groups
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use explicit join syntax and a count(distinct...):

```
select c.name, count(distinct u.id)
from companies c
inner join users u
  on u.company_id = c.id
inner join users_groups ug
  on ug.user_id = u.id
where ug.group_id = 1
group by c.name
```

for all companies:

```
select c.name, count(distinct u.id)
from companies c
left join users u
  on u.company_id = c.id
left join users_groups ug
  on ug.user_id = u.id
  and ug.group_id = 1
group by c.name
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any idea how to write the query so it will return all companies (also the one that has no admins). I tried to replace 'inner join' with 'left join' but doesn't seam to do the trick.

Comment: Thanks again! Now I am trying to filter so that only admins who have users.active = 1 will be included in the COUNT and again, the result to show all companies. grisbukten

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.name, COUNT(DISTINCT u.id) AS num_admins
    FROM groups AS g
    JOIN users_groups AS ug   ON ug.group_id = g.id
    JOIN users AS u           ON u.id = ug.user_id
    JOIN companies AS c       ON c.id = u.company_id
    WHERE g.group_id = 1
      AND g.name = 'admin'
    GROUP BY u.company_id;
```

It is unclear whether you need `COUNT(DISTINCT u.id)` or simply `COUNT(*)`.

I listed the 4 tables in the order they will be looked at.  (This is not a requirement, but makes it easier for a user to read and think through it.)  First is `groups` which has all the 'filtering`(`WHERE`).  Then it moves through the other tables all the way to getting the`company.name`.  Then the`GROUP BY`and its`COUNT(DISTINCT...)` are applied.

Tips on many:many schema (users_groups) design:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

`groups` -- group_id`and`group.name`are in a 1:1 relationship, yes?  If you know that it is`group_id = 1`, you can get rid of the table`groups`completely from the query.  If not, then be sure to have`INDEX(name)` in that table.